# Unattended Uninstall of IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, batch-file, uninstall, unattended

I know there are scripts available on the Microsoft website to have an unattended installation of IIS, but I was wondering if there is anyone who can help me out with a script to have an unattended uninstall of IIS?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

On Server 2008 you have two tools to install and un-install Windows components
ocsetup.exe and pkgmgr.exe.

When calling any of it, you need to specify the name of the component to un-install.

On 2008 I don't know how to get a list of the installed components, so you can just un-install any possible components.

The following would un-install the components I usually use:

```
start /w pkgmgr.exe /quite /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-Security;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-FTPServer;IIS-FTPSvc;IIS-FTPExtensibility;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-ManagementConsole
```

However you may have other IIS components installed. In theory when specifying IIS-WebServerRole related components should be un-installed as well. I haven't tested any of this because I don't have a 2008 Server anymore.

You can find a [full list of the component names on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748930%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), just include any component you need to un-install.